# CakePHP Search Plugin Repopulate Date

Tags: date, cakephp, search, plugins

I am using the [search plugin by CakeDC](https://github.com/CakeDC/search).

I have filtering between dates working, but after performing a search the Date dropdowns are not repopulated with the searched date.

Can anyone figure out why my date forms are not repopulating?  I thought it might be because I am converting the date to a string in the or conditions, but as far as I can tell the or Conditions demand a string.

Here is the code:

Model

```
public $filterArgs = array(
'from_date'  => array('type' => 'query', 'method' => 'orConditionsFromDate'),
'end_date'   => array('type' => 'query', 'method' => 'orConditionsEndDate'),
);

public function orConditionsFromDate($data = array()) {
    $filterFrom = $data['from_date'];
    $fromString = "$filterFrom[year]-$filterFrom[month]-01";
    $cond = array(
            'MovieStar.reject_date >=' => $fromString,
        );
    return $cond;
}

public function orConditionsEndDate($data = array()) {
    $filterEnd = $data['end_date'];
    $endString = "$filterEnd[year]-$filterEnd[month]-$filterEnd[day]";
    debug('$data');
    debug($data);
    $cond = array(
            'MovieStar.reject_date <=' => $endString,
        );
    return $cond;
}

public function getFromDateFormOptions(){
    $dateFieldOptions['type'] = 'date';
    $dateFieldOptions['div'] = array( 'style' => 'width:180px');
    $dateFieldOptions['required'] = false;
    $dateFieldOptions['maxYear'] = date('Y');

    $fromDateFieldOptions = $dateFieldOptions;
    $fromMonth =  date('m') - 1;
    $fromYear =  date('Y');
    if($fromMonth == 0){
        $fromMonth = 12;
        $fromYear = $fromYear - 1;
    }
    $fromDateFieldOptions['selected'] = array('day' => 1, 'month' => $fromMonth, 'year' => $fromYear  );
    $fromDateFieldOptions['label'] = 'From';
    //$myFromDateFormField = $this->Form->input('from_date', $fromDateFieldOptions);
    //return $myFromDateFormField;
    return $fromDateFieldOptions;
}

public function getEndDateFormOptions(){
    $dateFieldOptions['type'] = 'date';
    $dateFieldOptions['div'] = array( 'style' => 'width:180px');
    $dateFieldOptions['required'] = false;
    $dateFieldOptions['maxYear'] = date('Y');

    $endDateFieldOptions = $dateFieldOptions;
    $endDate = date('t');  // last day of current month
    $endDateFieldOptions['selected'] = array('day' => $endDate, 'month' => date('m'), 'year' => date('Y'));
    $endDateFieldOptions['label'] = 'To';
    //$myEndDateFormField = $this->Form->input('end_date', $endDateFieldOptions);
    //return $myEndDateFormField;   
    return $endDateFieldOptions;
}
```

View:

```
    <?php 
    echo $this->Form->create('MovieStar', array(
        'url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'index'), $this->params['pass'])
    ));
?>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <?php   echo $this->Form->input('from_date', $myFromDateFormOptions); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php   echo $this->Form->input('end_date', $myEndDateFormOptions); ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
    echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search'), array());
    echo $this->Form->end(); 
?>
```

Controller

```
    $myFromDateFormOptions = $this->MovieStar->getFromDateFormOptions();
    $myEndDateFormOptions = $this->MovieStar->getEndDateFormOptions();


    $this->set(compact('myFromDateFormOptions'));
    $this->set(compact('myEndDateFormOptions'));
```

Comment: try changing the `$endDateFieldOptions['selected'] = array(...)` into `$endDateFieldOptions['default'] = array(...);` and of course the same for  $fromDate...

Comment: Just use `echo $this->Form->create('MovieStar')`. No need to manually adjust the url. See https://github.com/CakeDC/search/pull/116

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Arilia - $endDateFieldOptions['default'] fixed it.   Mark your suggestion didn't fix the problem but everything still works as it did.  I am glad to remove the unnecessary code!

Comment: One more question regarding search you guys might be able to help me with.  Please.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259893/cakephp-get-field-totals-after-search-plugin-filtering