# CakePHP Get Field Totals After Search Plugin Filtering

Tags: search, cakephp, filter, plugins

I am trying to get the field totals for all results after filtering with the CakeDC search plugin.

In my model I have:

```
public function getFieldAmountTotal( $fieldNames){
    // Can't use recursive -1 because it includes current filtering
    // This will only grab the total by id
    // Can't not pull id because filtering on related tables
    //$totalAmounts = $this->find( 'all', array('fields' => $fieldNames));
    $totalAmounts = $this->find( 'all', array('fields' => $fieldNames, 'group' => 'MovieStar.id'));
    $grandTotal = array();
    foreach($fieldNames as $fieldName){
            $grandTotal[$fieldName] = 0;
    }
    foreach($totalAmounts as $amount){
        foreach($fieldNames as $fieldName){
                $grandTotal[$fieldName] += $amount['MovieStar'][$fieldName];
        }
    }
    debug('$grandTotal');
    debug($grandTotal);
    return $grandTotal;
}
```

This worked great when I was using the CakePHP filter plugin because all filtering was stored in the session and was automatically passed in.

How would I filter in the find using the current filter plugin form settings?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way to do it.  I pass the rows from the controller to the model.

Model:

```
public function getFieldAmountTotal($rowArray, $fieldNames){
        // Can't use recursive -1 because it includes current filtering
        // This will only grab the total by id
        // Can't not pull id because filtering on related tables
        //$totalAmounts = $this->find( 'all', array('fields' => $fieldNames));
        $totalAmounts = $this->find( 'all', array('fields' => $fieldNames, 'group' => 'MovieStar.id'));
        $grandTotal = array();
        foreach($fieldNames as $fieldName){
                $grandTotal[$fieldName] = 0;
        }
        //foreach($totalAmounts as $amount){
        foreach($rowArray as $thisRow){
            foreach($fieldNames as $fieldName){
                    $grandTotal[$fieldName] += $thisRow['MovieStar'][$fieldName];
            }
        }
        debug('$grandTotal');
        debug($grandTotal);
        return $grandTotal;
    }
```

Controller:

```
$this->Prg->commonProcess();
        $this->paginate = array( 'conditions' => $this->MovieStar->parseCriteria($this->Prg->parsedParams()), 'limit' => 100);
        $movieStars = $this->paginate();

        // Get total amounts for stars
        $amountFields = array('amount','loss_axis', 'loss_mgr1', 'loss_mgr2', 'loss_rep');
        $reject_totals = $this->MovieStar->getFieldAmountTotal($movieStars, $amountFields);
```

Result:

```
array(
    'amount' => (float) 4074.97,
    'loss_axis' => (float) 22,
    'loss_mgr1' => (float) 0,
    'loss_mgr2' => (float) 0,
    'loss_rep' => (float) 0
)
```